# Are there any C# libraries to connect to a Cardano node/acting as a wrapper for cardano-cli?

Tags: cardano-cli, c#

There are a few libraries in other languages ([Java](https://github.com/bloxbean/cardano-client-lib), [JavaScript](https://github.com/Berry-Pool/cardanocli-js), ...) that act as an abstraction layer between the Cardano node or the `cardano-cli` and your own code. I'm looking for a C# library that can do the same.

I found the following 2 libraries:

- https://github.com/tugolukov/cardano (built on the old REST API of Daedalus I think)
- https://github.com/KanLei/AdaSharp (seems like a rough prototype)

They both haven't been updated in 2 years and to me it doesn't look like they are in a usable state. So are there any other projects to connect to a Cardano node using C#? Or has anybody any experience with making calls to the `cardano-cli` from C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new library called [CardanoSharp.Wallet](https://github.com/CardanoSharp/cardanosharp-wallet) which can be used to generate mnemonics, create private and public keys, create addresses, build transactions and sign transactions.

As of now this seems to be the only C# library out there.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is a feature JS library wrapping cardano-cli.
Link: https://github.com/Berry-Pool/cardanocli-js

Kindly refer to https://developers.cardano.org/tools for further information on tools available for developers.

There are plans for developing tools and wrappers for a variety of languages.
I will update this space in case any good community project pops up.